# Is invoking FloatingActionButton.hide() the same as setting the visiblity of the FloatingActionButton as Gone?

Tags: android, visibility, floating-action-button

Just wanted to clear up a conceptual doubt. Is the hide() function of floating action button analogous to visibility.GONE or visibility.INVISIBLE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: yes.

Here is the implemntation of this function for ICS (Android SKD 15) taken from Design support library:

```
@Override
void hide(@Nullable final InternalVisibilityChangedListener listener, final boolean fromUser) {
    if (mIsHiding || mView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
        // A hide animation is in progress, or we're already hidden. Skip the call
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onHidden();
        }
        return;
    }

    if (!ViewCompat.isLaidOut(mView) || mView.isInEditMode()) {
        // If the view isn't laid out, or we're in the editor, don't run the animation
        mView.internalSetVisibility(View.GONE, fromUser);
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onHidden();
        }
    } else {
        mView.animate().cancel();
        mView.animate()
                .scaleX(0f)
                .scaleY(0f)
                .alpha(0f)
                .setDuration(SHOW_HIDE_ANIM_DURATION)
                .setInterpolator(AnimationUtils.FAST_OUT_LINEAR_IN_INTERPOLATOR)
                .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    private boolean mCancelled;

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                        mIsHiding = true;
                        mCancelled = false;
                        mView.internalSetVisibility(View.VISIBLE, fromUser);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                        mIsHiding = false;
                        mCancelled = true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        mIsHiding = false;
                        if (!mCancelled) {
                            mView.internalSetVisibility(View.GONE, fromUser);
                            if (listener != null) {
                                listener.onHidden();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Basically it is just changing visibility with animation.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you